# How can I use multiple Oauth2 SSO Servers on a single Spring boot application with Spring Cloud Security Oauth2?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-web

I'd like to give users the option to login to a Spring Boot web application using their Google or Facebook account.

I checked [The Spring Cloud Security documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/spring-cloud-security.html) and also [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-security/issues/63) to add such SSO functionality, but on both they only show how to configure one SSO server, so it's either Google or Facebook.

How can I add both options? on the web front-end I will add a button for each option so the users can choose which account to use, either Google or Facebook.

Or I am choosing the wrong package and should use something different altogether to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically have to install a separate authentication filter for each provider. There's a tutorial here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the link. So it means that I don't need spring-cloud-security-oauth2 package? on the link I see they use plain spring-security

Comment: Correct (since Spring Boot 1.3).

Comment: @DaveSyer may be a little late to the party, but using multiple authentication servers leads to other problems (e.g. it is difficult to figure out which token came from which OAuth server). Is there a way to set up one central OAuth server that "converts" external access tokens into local tokens and use the tokens of the central OAuth server instead?

Comment: There's a sample app the tutorial I linked to that does precisely that.

Comment: @DaveSyer if I understand the example correctly, the `/user` endpoint is your "common ground" to unify user authorization information. This seems to imply some server-side state information, i.e. the server needs to store some additional information wrt. the token. Is the same process possible with JWT?

Comment: Yes of course. Why not? (And the /user endpoint is just an example. Not every auth server has to have it.)

Comment: @DaveSyer In my understanding, with an externally generated JWT Access token, I cannot add any information to the token (since it is signed) and a JWT Access Token has no information about the issuer. Thus, I cannot distinctly map a JWT to a user. This, in return, impllies that the server needs to store some information related to each access token, defeating the point of JWT (i.e. statelessness). Could we discuss this elsewhere, e.g. in chat? I do not want to spam the comment section.

Comment: I'm traveling at the minute so probably not very responsive. You can send me an email if you like (easy to discover, e.g. via github).